# Panel is not getting displayed when the page is loading for the first time using JQuery

Tags: jquery, .net

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>

<script type="text/javascript" 
src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js">
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
   $(function () {
    $('select[id$=ddlCardType]').change(function () {
        if (this.value == -1) {
            $('div[id$=Panel1]').show();
            $('div[id$=Panel2]').hide();
        }
        else {
            $('div[id$=Panel1]').hide();
            $('div[id$=Panel2]').show();
        }
    });

});
</script>

</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server">
    <asp:ListItem Text="Select" Value="-1" />
    <asp:ListItem Value="1" Text="Text1" />
    <asp:ListItem Value="2" Text="Text2" />
    <asp:ListItem Value="3" Text="Text3" />
    <asp:ListItem Value="4" Text="Text4" />
    <asp:ListItem Value="5" Text="Text5" />
</asp:DropDownList>
<asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" Style="display: none;">
    Lorem Ipsum Lorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem Ipsum
</asp:Panel>
<asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" Style="display: none;">
    This si panel 2
</asp:Panel>

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

The above written code is not working when page is loaded for the first time.
i.e 
When  when page is loaded for the first time Panel1 should be visible.
But it's not happening.
Only after you do changes in drop down it's working correctly.

Please advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove this:

```
Style="display: none;"
```

The select is hidden until the change event is executed. If you of some reason need the display:hidden in the style, you can change your javascript instead:

```
$(function() {
    $('select[id$=DropDownList1]').change(function() {
        if (this.value == -1) {
            $('div[id$=Panel1]').show();
        }
    }).change();

});
```

it will simply execute the change event when page is loaded.

Comment: Yo, just a quick question - even though its `ID=Panel1` or what this ==> `'div[id$=Panel1]'` do? will `.net` make it dynamic ID? `:)`

Comment: @aaberg :When I am removing Style="display: none;" ,it is displaying both the panels simultaneously , which is not my requirement.
I need to display the panel corresponding to selected value in dropdown list .

Comment: @aaberg please see the edited code , as there are two panels.
$(function () {
        $('select[id$=ddlCardType]').change(function () {
            if (this.value == -1) {
                $('div[id$=Panel1]').show();
                $('div[id$=Panel2]').hide();
            }
            else {
                $('div[id$=Panel1]').hide();
                $('div[id$=Panel2]').show();
            }
        });

    });
When I am removing Style="display: none;" , both the panels will display simultaneously , which is not my requirement.

Comment: I don't see `Panel2` in your question's example code. I see it in the js, sure, but not anywhere else.

Comment: @aaberg , Just got the solution.

Comment: @palakmehta great you found a solution :) Was the solution to call change() after the page is loaded?